# Opening a modal after closing another gives incorrect modal layout

Tags: python, plotly-dash

In Dash, I define a layout as follows:

```
def layout(**other_unknown_query_strings):
    return dbc.Container([
        # ... other components ...
        error_modal(),
        reservation_modal(),
    ])
```

In my callback, I close one modal and open the other:

```
@callback(
    Output('error-modal', 'is_open'),
    Output('reservation-modal', 'is_open'),
    # ... other outputs ...
)
def reserve(...):
    return True, False
```

The `reservation-modal` closes as expected, and the `error-modal` opens. However, the UI is incorrect.

[image: Incorrect modal]

Modal code:

```
def error_modal():
    return dbc.Modal(
        [
            dbc.ModalHeader("Error"),
            dbc.ModalBody("Incorrect signum"),
            dbc.ModalFooter(
            dbc.Button("OK", id="error-modal-ok", className="ml-auto", n_clicks=0)
            ),
        ],
        id="error-modal",
    )
```

I suspect this is because I open one modal and close another.
I attempted to trigger another callback from the first to open the error modal, but the same error persists.